# Div not expanding to width of contents

Tags: html, css

If you look at the following [Website](http://beta.vacationnegotiation.com/)

the `container` class has a minimum width of 970px to prevent the website squashing down below that resolution. If you resize your browser to below this resolution and then scroll to the right you will see that the footer div that has the id `footer` doesn't stretch to fit the width of contents and so the grey background stops. Anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting a min width of 970px on footer sorted the problem

Answer (score 0):

the `footer` sits as a sibling of the `.container` div. In addition, you can see the the `footer` also contains a `.container` div inside it so its content will still align with the rest of the page's content.

Answer (score 0):

On lower res you need to have a different class for the divs inside the footer

```
<div class="col-xs-3">
                <!-- logo -->
                <a href="http://beta.vacationnegotiation.com/" id="logo">
                    <img src="http://beta.vacationnegotiation.com//assets/img/layout/logo_ftr.png" alt="Vacation Negotiation" class="img-responsive">
                </a>
                <!-- /logo -->
            </div>
```

should be

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3">
                <!-- logo -->
                <a href="http://beta.vacationnegotiation.com/" id="logo">
                    <img src="http://beta.vacationnegotiation.com//assets/img/layout/logo_ftr.png" alt="Vacation Negotiation" class="img-responsive">
                </a>
                <!-- /logo -->
            </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The `container` element within the `footer` element *is* adhering to the `minimum-width` css, but the `footer` element itself does not have the `min-width`. This means that your background colour won't stretch. The content, however, has a minimum width of `970px`, as demonstrated by this screengrab:

[image]

Re-organise your markup, or give the `footer` a `min-width` also:

```
.container,
.footer {

  min-width: 970px;

}
```

Comment: It has a div with a class of `container` inside it with